# Bootstrap carousel caption on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, caption

I am using a bootstrap carousel and i need to show the caption on hover only

I know i need to do something with CSS

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">                        
                        <div class="col-md-2">   
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb11"> </a>                               
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3 >Caption Text</h3>
                                    <p >This is some text<p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb12"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb13"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb14"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb21"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="pic.jpg" alt="Thumb22"></a>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carousel-caption").hide();
    $("img[alt=thumb11").on("hover",function(){
        $(".carousel-caption").fadeIn();
    });
});
```